# python + selenium - how to select the dropdown list which the hidden = true

Tags: python, selenium

I'm beginner both in Selenium, and I want to select the option of the dropdown. But it always doesn't work with the error message "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: "

the HTML code is below

```
<div id="template-select-dialog" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" data-keyboard="true" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false" hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="modal-body-title">
<div class="modal-body-message">
<div class="template-names">
<select id="template-select-dialog_template-names">
<option class="select-none"></option>
<option value="Sample server">Sample server</option>
<option value="Sample network">Sample network</option>
<option value="Sample server in network">Sample server in network</option>
<option value="KST stack">KST stack</option>
<option value="KST stack for LRT">KST stack for LRT</option>
</select>
```

my selenium code is below

```
dropM = browser.find_element_by_id("template-select-dialog_template-names")
dropM.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='KST stack for LRT']").click()
```

I don't know the reason whether is the " hidden="true" " or not, so shall you give me some advice, thank you !

Comment: Can you consider to update the exact manual steps your are trying to perform? Consider updating the snapshot of the dropdown. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is special class to dealing with dropdown select elements

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("template-select-dialog_template-names"))
select.select_by_visible_text('KST stack for LRT')
```

More info is here - http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms

Comment: I had used this method, but there is a error message "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: "

Comment: It hard to say from just html code what is selenium-correct way to achieve what you want.  But you can try to execute javascript as workaround - `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('template-select-dialog').setAttribute("hidden", false);")`